# How to filter array of dates by date range?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have an array of objects. Each object contains a Date attribute.

I need to return an array of objects with date attributes. however, objects that have date attributes that are consecutive days (1 day apart), need to be within their own array.

example input:

```
const inputArray = [ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate];
```

example expected output:

```
// example output
const finalArray = [ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, [ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate], ObjectwDate, [ObjectwDate, ObjectwDate]];
```

I'm really lost on how to get this to work in all cases. So far I have something similar to the following:

```
 const rangeArray = [];
 const finalArray = [];

// sort input array for oldest date 
const format = inputArray.sort((a, b) => (
   new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
));

format.sort((aDate, bDate) => {
  if (differenceInDays(bDate.date, aDate.date) === 1) {
     rangeArray.push(aDate, bDate);
  }

  finalArray .push(bDate);
});
```

I feel as though this is not the most efficient way to solve my problem. I'm wondering if there is a better way to loop through the array, and put all objects with consecutive dates in their own array.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
I am using date-fns to calculate the difference in days:

https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInDays

Comment: What is `format` there?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry about that, I've fixed my  code here.

Answer (score 0):

After you sor your array, it should be fairly straight foward from there. Iterate through and push consecutives into an array. When you encounter a non-consec, push the current array into an array and start with a new one. If the array that you're pushing has a length of one, just push the item inside. Will provide sample code shortly

**UPDATE:**
Something along these lines, but still have to do something for the very last value, because there is no i + 1. The code below isn't functional :D

```js
function GroupConsecutiveDates(arrayOfDates)
{
  let outerArray = [];
  let innerArray = [];
  for(let i = 1; i < arrayOfDates.length; i++)
  {
    let currentDate = arrayOfDates[i];
    let nextDate = arrayOfDates[i + 1];
    let dateDifference = currentDate - nextDate;
    
    if(dateDifference > 1)
    {
      switch(innerArray.length)
      {
        case 0:
          break;
        case 1:
          outerArray.push(innerArray[0]);
        default:
          outerArray.push(innerArray);
      }
      innerArray = [currentDate];
      continue;
    }
    innerArray.push(currentDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
let dates = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  dates.push(randomDate(new Date(2018, 1, 5), new Date()));
}


dates = dates.sort((a, b) => a - b);



function GetDateDifference(date1, date2)
{
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
  return diffDays;
}

function CollectNearDates(arr)
{
  if(arr.length <= 1) return arr
  let outer = [];
  let inner = [arr[0]];
  let previousDate = inner[0];

  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    let currentDate = dates[i];
    let difference = GetDateDifference(previousDate, currentDate);
    if(difference <= 1)
    {
      inner.push(previousDate);
      previousDate = currentDate;
      continue;
    }
    switch(inner.length)
    {
      case 0:
        break;
      case 1:
        outer.push(inner[0]);
        break;
      default:
        outer.push(inner);
    }
    previousDate = currentDate;
    inner = [currentDate]

  }
  if(inner.length === 1) outer.push(previousDate);
  else inner.push(previousDate);
  return outer;
}

console.log(CollectNearDates(dates))
```